# Check if list is made up by bytes only - Prolog

Tags: prolog

I need to write a predicate that checks if the list is made up only by binary digits:

```
%Define a binary digit type

bind(0).

bind(1).

%Predicate

byte_list([]).

byte_list([X]):-
    bind(X).
```

Comment: Do you have some examples of what X would look like, in byte_list?

Comment: It should look like: ([bind(0),bind(1),bind(1),bind(0)]).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the version with the keyword `bind`:

```
byte_list([]).
byte_list([bind(H)|T]):- bind(H), byte_list(T).
```

Input example:

```
% False
byte_list([bind(0), bind(2)]).
% True
byte_list([bind(0), bind(1)]).
```

If you just want to check that the values belongs to `bind`:

```
byte_list([]).
byte_list([H|T]):- bind(H), byte_list(T).
```

Input example:

```
% False
byte_list(0, 2]).
% True
byte_list([0, 1]).
```

Answer (score 0):

With a grammar rule which describes a bit_list (bits, binary digits) as either an empty list, or a list element 0 or 1 which is followed by a bit_list.

```
bit_list --> [].
bit_list --> ([0] | [1]), bit_list.
```

e.g.

```
?- phrase(bit_list, [1,0,0,1,0]).
true

?- phrase(bit_list, [1,0,0,'',0]).
false
```

This can also generate bit lists:

```
?- length(Ls, 3), phrase(bit_list, Ls).
Ls = [0, 0, 0] ;
Ls = [0, 0, 1] ;
Ls = [0, 1, 0] ;
Ls = [0, 1, 1] ;
Ls = [1, 0, 0] ;
Ls = [1, 0, 1] ;
Ls = [1, 1, 0] ;
Ls = [1, 1, 1]
```